# Css centered layout with background spaning outside element

Tags: html, css

I have a quite simple layout but a hard problem.

**In short**

- My layout is centered
- The sidebar background should span all the way to the left
- The section background should span all the way to the right
- The backgrounds should only be visuals, the layout is still centered
- The sections has unknown height
- I've tried to solve it with css grid where I line it up as a full with layout but then I the grouping of the center is lost
- I've tried `:before` `:after` with position absolute but that fails when I use `overflow-y` scroll on the containers.
- I don't want to solve it with javascript

```css
html,
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

section.blue {
  background: blue;
 }
 
 section.yellow {
  background: yellow;
 }
 
 section.green {
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <div class="content">
      <section class="blue">Blue</section>
      <section class="yellow">Yellow</section>
      <section class="green">Green</section>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

### Image of how the result should look like

[image]

Comment: Change main width to 100% and set aside tekst-align to right. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below using CSS grid and some padding tricks:

```css
html,
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  background:#eee;
}

main { 
  background: linear-gradient(#ddd,#ddd) center/600px 100% no-repeat;  /*Color only 600px */
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:"aside aside content content";
  grid-template-columns:1fr 100px 500px 1fr
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area:aside;
  padding-left: calc(100% - 100px); /*the content inside only 100px on the right*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area:content;
}

section {
  padding-right:calc(100% - 500px); /*the content inside only 500px on the left*/
}

section.blue {background: blue;}
section.yellow {background: yellow;}
section.green {background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <div class="content">
      <section class="blue"> Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue</section>
      <section class="yellow">Yellow</section>
      <section class="green">Green</section>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Another idea with the same trick using flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  background:#eee;
}

main { 
  background: linear-gradient(#ddd,#ddd) center/600px 100% no-repeat;  /*Color only 600px */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis:100px; /* main width */
  flex-grow:1; 
  overflow-y: auto;
}
aside div {
    padding-left: calc(100% - 100px); /*the content inside only 100px on the right*/
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-basis:500px; /* main width */
  flex-grow:1;
}

section {
  padding-right:calc(100% - 500px); /*the content inside only 500px on the left*/
}

section.blue {background: blue;}
section.yellow {background: yellow;}
section.green {background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>
    <aside><div>Aside</div></aside>
    <div class="content">
      <section class="blue"> Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue</section>
      <section class="yellow">Yellow</section>
      <section class="green">Green</section>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using *CSS Grid layout* - maybe it's a bit of a verbose explanation, but there you go:

- place the `aside` and `content` into the second and third columns of  4-column grid (using `grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 500px 1fr`),
- extend the second column (`aside`) to the first using *negative margins* and padding:

  ```
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 300px);
  padding-left: calc(50vw - 300px);
  ```

  (note that `50vw - 300px` is the width of the leftmost and rightmost columns after the second and third occupy 600px)
- similarly extend the third column (`content`) using:

  ```
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 300px);
  padding-right: calc(50vw - 300px);
  ```
- the `content` is a *column flexbox* with a *pseduo element* that takes care of the background (if this is needed),
- the blue, yellow and green `section` backgrounds are extended now using `padding-right: calc(50vw - 300px)`.

See demo below:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  background: #ddd;
  display: grid; /* grid container */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 500px 1fr; /* 4 columns */
  height: 100%;
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-column: 2; /* place in second column */
  /* extend to first column */
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 300px);
  padding-left: calc(50vw - 300px);
}

.content {
  grid-column: 3; /* place in thrid column */
  /* extend to fourth column */
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 300px);
  padding-right: calc(50vw - 300px);
  /* column flexbox for the sections */
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content:after { /* serves as background*/
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
  background: #bbb;
}

section { /* extend sections to fourth column*/
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(50vw - 300px);
}

section.blue {
  background: blue;
}

section.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

section.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>
    <aside>Aside - some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here </aside>
    <div class="content">
      <section class="blue">Blue - some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here </section>
      <section class="yellow">Yellow - some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here </section>
      <section class="green">Green - some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```